# Using Obejct as key inside an object

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to use object as a key inside an object?

I found the answer to be `NO` but with no clear explaination.
Example:

```js
let user1 = { name: "John Doe" };
let numberOfAnswers = {}; // try to use an object

numberOfAnswers[user1] = 234; // try to use user1 object as the key
alert(numberOfAnswers) // [object][object]
```

But then what are we doing here? Why this seems to work? Are we not creating numberOfAnswers Object with user1 as key?

```js
let numberOfAnswers = {
   user1: {
      visits: 123;
   }
}
```

Comment: No. Object keys are either strings or Symbol instances. If you try anything else, it will be coerced to a string. You *can* use objects as keys in Map instances, however.

Comment: _"But then what are we doing here? Why this seems to work? Are we not creating numberOfAnswers Object with user1 as key?"_ - Just log the content of `numberOfAnswers` -> `console.log(numberOfAnswers)`

Comment: You are looking for `numberOfAnswers.user1 = { visits: 123 };` or something. If you want the key to be "John Doe", you need `numberOfAnswers[user1.name] = ...`

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to use object as a key inside an object?

No. Property keys are always strings or [`Symbol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)s, never objects. If you use an object as a property key, it's implicitly converted to a string (usually) or `Symbol` (if the object overrides the "to primitive" operation).

You can use objects as keys in [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instances, though.

> But then what are we doing here? Why this seems to work? Are we not creating numberOfAnswers Object with user1 as key?
>
> ```
> let numberOfAnswers = {
>    user1: {
>       visits: 123;
>    }
> }
> ```

No. You're creating an object with a property whose **key** is the string `"user1"` and whose **value** is an object.

Comment: That seems to clear the confusion Thanks!

Comment: So basically what it means is that whenever we create a key it gets converted to string so in case of object it results in ``[object][object]``. Lem me know if am wrong.

Comment: @TusharRoy - **Almost** always a string, but the object being used as a key can override that to end up with a `Symbol` instead (**very** much an edge case). The string may vary. With a plain object, the string will be `"[object Object]"`.

Comment: Thanks @T .J. Crowder